# proving $|| \vec{x} \times \vec{y}||^{2} = ||\vec{x}||^{2}||\vec{y}||^{2} - (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y})^{2}$ using index notation

Tags: linear-algebra, classical-mechanics

R.T.P  $|| \vec{x} \times \vec{y}||^{2} = ||\vec{x}||^{2}||\vec{y}||^{2} - (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y})^{2}$ using index notation.

where $\epsilon_{ijk} = \begin{cases} 1 : (i,j,k) \in \lbrace (1,2,3);(2,3,1);(3,1,2) \rbrace \\ -1: (i,j,k) \in \lbrace (1,3,2);(2,1,3);(3,2,1) \rbrace \\ 0: i=j;i=k;j=k  \end{cases}$

initially i used the fact that:

$\vec{x} \times \vec{y} = \epsilon_{ijk} \vec{e_{i}} x_{j} y_{k}$

and that

$|| \vec{x} \times \vec{y} || = \epsilon_{ijk} x_{j} y_{k}$

$|| \vec{x} \times \vec{y} ||^{2} = (\epsilon_{ijk} x_{j} y_{k})^{2}$

im unable to split it into 2 terms that is the main issue.

Comment: Have you tried expanding both sides and verifying that the resulting polynomials of $x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3$ are identical?

Comment: You're expression for $\| \vec x\times\vec y\|$ is already wrong, it shouldn't depend on $i$.

Comment: I think you're going to confuse yourself badly if you try to use implicit summation here. Your expression for $||\vec{x} \times \vec{y}||^2$ needs an outer sum over $i$.

Comment: @MaoWao The OP is using the Einstein summation convention.

Comment: @Alan Yes, but there is no summation in $i$ in his expression for $\|\vec x\times\vec y\|$.

Comment: Without indices: If you know that for orthogonal $a,b$ you have $\|a\times b\|=\|a\|\,\|b\|$, and the linear and anti-symmetric properties of the cross product, then $$\|y\|^2\,\|x×y\|=\|(\|y\|^2x-(x·y)y)×y\|=\|\|y\|^2x-(x·y)y\|\,\|y\|.$$ Now apply Pythagoras. $$\|y\|^2\,\|x×y\|^2=\|\|y\|^2x-(x·y)y\|^2=\|y\|^2(\|x\|^2\|y\|^2-2(x·y)^2+(x·y)^2).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe that the dot product $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$ of two vectors can be written as
$$\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=\delta_{ij}x_iy_j=x_iy_i,$$
and that the square of the norm $|\vec{x}\rvert^2 = \vec{x}\cdot \vec{x}$. Now,
\begin{align}\lvert\vec{x}\times \vec{y}\rvert^2&=(\vec{x}\times \vec{y})\cdot (\vec{x}\times\vec{y})\\
&= (\varepsilon_{ijk}x_jy_k)\:(\varepsilon_{ilm}x_ly_m) \\
&= (\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl})\:x_jx_ly_ky_m \\
&= x_jx_jy_ky_k-x_jy_jx_ky_k \\
&=|\vec{x}|^2|\vec{y}|^2-(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})^2.
\end{align}
We have also used the following identity:
$$\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{ilm}=\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}||x||^2||y||^2 -(x\cdot y)^2 & = \left(\sum_{j}x_j^2\right)\left(\sum_{k}y_k^2\right) - \left(\sum_{l}x_ly_l\right)^2 \\ 
&= \sum_{j\neq k}\left(x^2_jy_k^2 + x_k^2y_j^2-2x_jy_jx_ky_k\right) \\
& = \sum_{j\neq k}(x_jy_k - x_jy_k)^2 \\
& = \sum_{i}\left(\sum_{j}\sum_{k} \epsilon_{ijk}x_jy_k\right)^2 =||x\times y||^2
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: But that's not using index notation as required by the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I fix it now